# Github Actions Workflow: Unable to connect to the custom-built Docker Container's port via image://container-name:port/rest/of/path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions, github-actions-services

**My goal**: I'll commit a PR for a repo that triggers a GA Workflow. This includes building the Docker image for that repo along with other images.

All of their images are built by [checking out](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout#Checkout-multiple-repos-private) their repos b/c my team wants to avoid pulling their images. Thus, I cannot use the [service-containers workflow setup](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/about-service-containers) since it requires pulling images from Docker Hub or AWS ECR.

When running my GA Workflow, after docker-composing my containers, I'm unable to get feeds from my Docker Container's url (`image://container-name:port/rest/of/path`). Instead, I see this error `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

Other attempts:

1. Using http:/localhost:port/rest/of/path. Got same error `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`
2. Using the Docker Container's IP http:docker.ip:port/rest/of/path. Got different error `Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.18.0.6:8088 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect`
3. Create a Docker image of my tests, adding to the docker-compose file, and repeating the above steps. Same errors.

If this provides more context, I added a template of my *docker-compose.yml* below. Each of them except the db images have a repo. They depend on each other as follows

Containers: **C** -> **B** + **A** -> **db**

***tests** run against **C**

I start my GA workflow like below:

1. Start a PR for **C** and it triggers the GA Workflow
2. Checkout each of the above repos (except db, that’s public)
3. Build each of their images and then `docker-compose up`
4. Checkout my tests repo and run them against the **C**’s localhost url's feeds (C://C:3333/rest/of/path).

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: db
  db-seed:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: db_seed
    links:
      - db
    volumes_from:
      - db
    command:
      /import.sh
  A:
    image: ecr-aws/A
    container_name: api
    ports:
        - 1111:1111
    env_file:
      - 'A/.env'
    depends_on: 
      - db
  B:
    image: ecr-aws/B
    container_name: B
    ports:
      - 2222:2222
    env_file:
      - 'B/.env'
    depends_on: 
      - db
  C:
    image: ecr-aws/C
    container_name: C
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    env_file:
      - 'C/.env'
    depends_on:
      - A
```